# Iphone sdk not installed error while installing phonegap template

Tags: installation, cordova, vmware, iphone-sdk-3.2

I recently installed iPhone SDK on my Mac OS X 10.5 VMWare. I have iPhone SDK 3 installed on the vmware image. I planned to learn Phonegap development and so started to install the 'PhoneGap Template' for iPhone applications.

But when I start the installation, I get the error saying `iPhone SDK not found`. I already have installed the iPhone SDK, then why am I getting this error.

Can anybody help me?